Is Bash 3.2's PIPESTATUS + PROMPT_COMMAND broken?
I've been trying to expand my old Bash(3.2+) prompt that checks $? and reports
bright red error blocks to also include "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" ...
But from what I've been able to tell with the simplest reproductions below,
PIPESTATUS is always just ( 0 ) in 3.2 prompts and afterwards
(3.2.57 is the last Bash Apple will ever ship, so I'm trying to keep supporting that version)
Back in ~2.05 days Chet said

As for PIPESTATUS, I will change things so that it won't change as
the result of executing $PROMPT_COMMAND.
The end result should be that neither $PROMPT_COMMAND nor prompt string
expansion change $? or $PIPESTATUS.

...BUT PIPESTATUS always seems to be wrong in PROMPT_COMMAND in bash 3.2
Reproduction / Testing Bash 3.2 vs 5.2
prompt-x.sh -- Three sample prompts ( https://pastebin.com/xfhvWgq0 )

_p_simple
_p_return
_p_pipe
Full log with Bash 3.2 https://pastebin.com/erJNhNZ0
Full log with Bash 5.2 https://pastebin.com/DbviAfts

_p_simple () {
    unset PROMPT_COMMAND
    PS1='${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}: \$ '
}

# Save $?
_p_return_prompt_command () {
    save_rtn=$?
    : other commands
    return $save_rtn
}
_p_return () {
    PROMPT_COMMAND=_p_return_prompt_command
    PS1='${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}: $save_rtn \$ '
}

# Save ${PIPESTATUS[@]}, then derive $?
_p_pipe_prompt_command () {
    save_pipe=( "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" )
    save_rtn=${save_pipe[ $(( ${#save_pipe[@]} - 1)) ]}
    : other commands
    return $save_rtn
}
_p_pipe () {
    PROMPT_COMMAND=_p_pipe_prompt_command
    PS1='${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}: $save_rtn (${save_pipe[*]}) \$ '
}

printf '_p_simple\n  or: _p_return\n  or: _p_pipe\n'
_p_simple

Of course 5.2 does the right thing, but
3.2 with _p_return: can only report AND preserve $? (not PIPESTATUS)
3: 0 $ false
3: 1 $ echo "$?" "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
1 0
3: 0 $ echo a | cat | grep x
3: 1 $ echo "$?" "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
1 0
3: 0 $ echo a | cat | grep x ; echo "$?" "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
1 0

Similarly, 3.2 with _p_pipe: works for $? but still not PIPESTATUS

Please create and post a [mcve] (no images, no links, just concise, testable sample input, expected output and the smallest amount of code we need to reproduce your problem) so we can help you.

I don't have Mac but 3.2.57 built on Ubuntu 22.04 from original GNU source behaves as apparently desired, not as shown above

I can't reproduce this either. Run bash --norc and try again, perhaps something else in your .bashrc is causing this

Please use a [repro].

bash 3.2.57 should probably only be used as a POSIX-compatible shell. If you really want to use bash, install a newer version with HomeBrew, Nix, etc. Otherwise, consider using zsh instead.
